# SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '{search_term}''

Tags: php, jquery, search

I can't do the live search table thing. Can someone help me please?
Here is my code. I want to show only the data I've search.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
<?php

//include the connection file
include "conn.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblreservation";
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
        $sql .= "WHERE Name = '{search_term}'";
}

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
 <form name="search_form" method="POST" action="trys.php" align="center">
 Search: <input type="text" name="search_box" value="" />
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search the table...">
 </form>
 <table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5">

 <tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Email</td>
<td>Packages</td>
      <td><select name="Packages" class="fieldsize">
      <option value="">select package</option>
      <option value="budget" <?php if($valid_Packages=='budget') echo     "selected='selected'";?>>Budget</option>
      <option value="standard" <?php if($valid_Packages=='standard') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Standard</option>
      <option value="super" <?php if($valid_Packages=='super') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Super</option>
      <option value="mega" <?php if($valid_Packages=='mega') echo "selected='selected'";?>>Mega</option>
    </select>
    <span class="err"><?php echo $error["Packages"];?></span></td>
</tr>
<td>Contactno</td>
<td>Gender</td>
      <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php     if($valid_gender=='male') echo "checked='checked'";?> />
    Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if($valid_gender=='female')    echo "checked='checked'";?>/>
    Female <span class="err"><?php echo $error["gender"];?></span></td>
<td>file</td>
      <td><input type="file" name="file" value="upload" />
    <span class="err"><?php echo $error["file"];?></span></td>
<td>Address</td>
</tr>
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<td><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Email']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Packages']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Contactno']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Gender']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['file']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['Address']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Try adding a space before the word "WHERE" --> " WHERE "

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `$` and a space in this line:

```
$sql .= "WHERE Name = '{search_term}'";
```

The correct line should be as follows:

```
$sql .= " WHERE Name = '{$search_term}' ";
```

The SQL statement you are currently generating is exactly this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblreservationWHERE Name = '{search_term}'
```

Additionally, I would recommend checking for the existence of `$_POST['search_box']` rather than `$_POST['search']` in your if-statement and that it actually has a value before appending it as this is what you actually want to use in your query:

```
if (isset($_POST['search_box']) && $_POST['search_box']) {
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
    $sql .= " WHERE Name = '{$search_term}' ";
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that mysql_* is deprecated, and this code is open to injection attack.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` should negate SQL injection attacks barring any unfixed bugs in the library, however I agree that `mysql_*()` is deprecated and that such bugs may not be fixed. I recommend the OP switches the code to use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli_connect) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo).

Comment: What is the content of `$sql` immediately prior to `$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`?